# Warning C4451: Usage of ref class BackgroundTaskDeferral can lead to invalid marshaling

Tags: windows-10, uwp

Regarding my [universal app project](https://github.com/anhoavu/BackgroundServer), I am getting compilation warning:

*warning C4451: 'BackgroundServerTasks::ServerTask::Run::::deferral': Usage of ref class 'Windows::ApplicationModel::Background::BackgroundTaskDeferral' inside this context can lead to invalid marshaling of object across contexts*

*note: Consider using 'Platform::Agile' instead*

in [this file](https://github.com/anhoavu/BackgroundServer/blob/master/BackgroundServerTasks/ServerTask.cpp). How could I resolve this warning? Apparently, it is due to my using the `BackgroundTaskDeferral` within a `create_task`. I found no solution on Bing except for [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/314b5826-0a66-4307-abfe-87b8052c3c07/agile-pointer-warning-in-release-build?forum=winappswithnativecode) which dismisses the problem but I am not sure if it is applicable in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It surprises me that `Windows::ApplicationModel::Background::BackgroundTaskDeferral` is not agile.

Try completing the deferral in the same context, i.e.:

```
create_task(writer->StoreAsync()).then([this, deferral](unsigned int n)
{
    deferral->Complete();
}, task_continuation_context::use_current());
```

Another option is to use a `Platform::Agile<>` wrapper:

```
Platform::Agile<Windows::ApplicationModel::Background::BackgroundTaskDeferral> Deferral;

// ...

Deferral = taskInstance->GetDeferral();
```

Comment: Wrapping it with `Platform::Agile` does resolve the warning.